# Не могу разобраться с терминологией ООП

Tags: java, ооп

Читаю книгу по Java и запутался в терминах.

Например сложно понять термины вроде `объект`, `класс`, `метод`, `конструктор`, `артрибут`.

Кто может ну очень популярно их объяснить?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Класс эта некая сущность,  являющаяся базовой в ооп языке. Она может представлять некий объект из реального мира или предметной области. Обычно в классе определяется некоторое поведение, оно выражается в виде методов. Так же у класса, могут быть какие то свойства - это атрибуты или поля класса.
- Объект - это экземпляр какого то класса. Приведу аналогию из реального мира, есть фрукт яблоко -  это класс, а конкретный объект данного класса, это плод который висит на дереве или лежит на прилавке магазина.
- Конструктор - это особый метод, который позволяет создавать объекты данного класса.
- Атрибут - это внутреннее состояние или свойство объекта, Например, если вернуться к яблокам, атрибутом для них могут быть цвет, размер, сорт и пр.
- Методы - это некие действия, которые можно выполнить над объектом. Например, у человека могут быть определены методы `run`,`sleep`,`eat` и пр.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class DataStructure {

    // Свойства класса
    private int size = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[size];    

    //Конструктор по-умолчанию, так как не принимает никаких параметров
    //нужен для того что  бы в момент инициализации этого обьекта
    //можно было так же проинициализировать его поля(свойства)
    //если в этом конечно  есть необходимость.
    public DataStructure() {
        //do nothing
    }

    //Конструктор который принимает на вход 
    //переменную типа int и этой же переменной
    //инициализирует сойство класа this.size
    public DataStructure(int i) {
        this.size = i;
    }

    //Метод класса может использоваться для: 
    //изминения свойств самого объекта, получения информации об объекте,
    //выполнения операции над данными которые в него передают или над 
    //данными самого этого обьекта.
    public void printEven() {
        System.out.println("Size:"  + size);
    }

    //метод просто возвращает информацию об одном из своих свойств
    public  int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    //метод изменяет свойство объекта 
    public void setSize(int i){
        this.size = i;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Создаем экземпляры класса
        DataStructure dataStructure = new DataStructure();
        DataStructure dataStructure2 = new DataStructure(23423);

        /*В этом примере dataStructure - это объект(экземпляпр) класса DataStructure
        */

        //достаем данные из объекта
        int size = dataStructure.getSize();//15 
        int size2 = dataStructure2.getSize();//23423

        //изменяем свойство объекта
        dataStructure.setSize(42);

        //вызываем метод который не изменяет свойств
        //а просто выводит информацию в консоль
        dataStructure.printEven();//42
    }
}
```